# Asymptotic for binary linear code

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory

Let $C=[n,k,d]$ is a binary linear code of length $n$, dimension $k$, and minimum distance $d$. Let us consider all possible binary linear codes with $k=d$ and $n\in \mathbb N$. Is it true that
$$A=\mathop{\lim }\limits_{k\to \infty } \frac{k}{n}=0\ ?$$
I look [codetables.de](http://codetables.de/) and this assumption looks plausible. Are suitable boundaries or hypotheses known?

Comment: I assume you want the number of codes, not just $\frac kn$, in your limit.  For fixed $n$, once $k \gt \frac n2$ there are no codes

Comment: @RossMillikan $n=n(k)$ and $n→\infty $ as $k→\infty $, of course. From your comments it follows that $A=\mathop{\lim \sup }_{k→\infty }k/n \le 1/2$. Сan there exist codes $[10k,k,k]$ for arbitrarily large $k$? If such codes exist only a finite number, no more, then $A \le 1/10$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gilbert Varshamov bound shows the existence of a binary linear code of dimension $$k\geq n-\lfloor \log_2 V(n,d-1)\rfloor,$$
where $V(n,r)$ is the volume of the hamming sphere in the $n$ dimensional hypercube.

Let $d=k$, and find the maximal $k$ satisfying this equation, for each $n$. Along a subsequence of integers, something like the existence of codes with parameters
$$
[Ak_i,k_i,k_i]
$$
with $A=5,$ should hold.

More generally, let $n\rightarrow \infty$ and use the fact that for each $n$ the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k},$ are superincreasing in $k$ up to about $k<n/3,$ and the approximation
$$
V(n,k-1)\approx \binom{n}{k} \approx 2^{n (h(k/n)+o(1))},
$$
where $h$ is binary Shannon entropy (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236508/are-there-good-bounds-on-binomial-coefficients/236511#236511)) to conclude that the solution $\theta=0.227\cdots$ to
$$
1-\theta=h(\theta)
$$
where $\theta=k/n,$ means that asymptotically there is a sequence of codes with parameters $[Ak,k,k]$ and $A=1/\theta.$

Comment: This is very useful for me. Many thanks!